# Mpd wont update my library, using external drive?

Tags: music, music-player, mpd

using ncmpc++ ver 0.5.6 on ubuntu 12.04 <<- Epic AwesomeWM so thats why im using the terminal music playa!

Anyway I edited the `mpd.conf` in `/etc/mpd.conf`

under the music library I put `/media/Jake External/Torrents`

but for w/e reason ncmpc++ still has no songs loaded in it :(

I made the `/torrents` directory to Executable <- from a google search!

I changed the auto update to true and uncommented it

Then changed the auto dir depth to 5 cause its all organized!

But nothing has helped :(

What now Ask Ubuntu people?!

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Wiki documentation page for mpd player](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Configuration).

[image: Configuration settings]

You need to ensure you follow these steps when setting up your file locations